# Bytes read in reverse order from file C++

Tags: c++, file, endianness

I want to extract an unsigned integer from a binary file.

Here is the code I wrote:

```cpp
std::ifstream is(path, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

uint32_t count;
is.read((char*)&count, 4);

std::cout << count << std::endl;
```

The beginning of the file is `00 00 EA 60`, and so I should get `60000`.

Instead of that, I get `1625948160`, which is `60 EA 00 00`.

**EDIT:**

I am asking if there is a way to have the std::ifstream reverse the bytes itself, i.e. by reading the bytes in reverse order?

I find it overkill to reverse each integers afterward if there is a way to have them read backward from the start

Comment: Strange that you know enough to tag your question with `endianess` but don't know enough that this concept completely explains your issue. Reversing the bytes is what you have to do.

Comment: @john I am asking if there is a way to have the std::ifstream reverse the bytes itself, I.e. by reading the bytes in reverse order.

I find it overkill to reverse each integers afterward if there is a way to have them read backward from the start

Comment: @Sinder How would it know which bytes to reverse? Should it reverse the first two bytes? The first seven bytes? The first twenty three bytes?

Comment: @Sinder No there is no way to make the ifstream reverse the bytes for you.

Comment: Ok I got your point. Thank you I will stick to the `ntohl()` function then